# Convert filepaths from long to short format

Tags: cmd, windows-xp

I have a folder of many .M3U files each containing a list of file references, e.g.

```
\Dance\00724347388620-1-1.flac
\Dance\00724347388620-1-11.flac
\Dance\00724347388620-1-15.flac
\Spacers\02480002928928-1-44.flac
```

How can I convert these to short filename format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%m IN ('dir /b *.m3u') DO (
 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%%m") DO ECHO %%~sa
)>%%~nmshort.m3u


GOTO :EOF
```

Each existing playlist will be converted to `samenameshort.mp3` - provided the file mentioned in the list exists.

Comment: Do the files exist on `D:` as the report suggests? If you don't want the drivename, use `~spnxa` in place of `~sa`. The system can't evaluate a shortname for a file that does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, that comment of mine was referring to files erroneously missing, hence comment deleted.

Comment: And now see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450682/convert-filepaths-from-long-to-short-format :)